# I want to use desimal value only one time - flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to make textfield in which user can press decimal(.) only once after that is not clickable in textField

How can I do that?

For reference I attach video of what I want to achieve

Here is video Link :-
[reference video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SpFHixIPcIlRUz57BJg_is3jO80Eq5Ki/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you can do custom click or ignore `.` on next click

Comment: Start with the documentation about [text field change handlers](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes). But if you still run into a problem, then ask a more focused question.

Comment: @yeasin I attach video for better understanding

Comment: @DipakRamoliya Yes, the requirements were already clear without the video, but SO is not the place to ask for coding services, check the docs I linked above, show us what you have tried (show the existing code), and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: @Ma3x but I am stuck at this time because I don't know how to do it and I can't find any references about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this on your `inputFormatters` of your **TextField**

```
TextInputFormatter.withFunction(
                                        (oldValue, newValue) {
                                      try {
                                        final text = newValue.text;
                                        if (text.isNotEmpty) double.parse(text);
                                        return newValue;
                                      } catch (e) {}
                                      return oldValue;
                                    }),
```